# Phonegap Build in Dreamweaver CS6 - old project runs in emulator instead of current one

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, dreamweaver, phonegap-build

I created four or five little test Android apps in Dreamweaver CS6 using PhoneGap Build. Each time, the current app would run in the emulator. Now, instead of running the project in the current site, the emulator64-arm keeps running a previous project when I click the PhoneGap Build icon on the Android emulator home screen.  I have tried deleting all my projects from build.phonegap.com, and deleting all but the most recent project from the local drive. Even so, the emulator runs the old project -- which as far as I know, doesn't even exist anymore, either locally or on build.phonegap.com!  Do I need to delete the project from the emulator? If so, how would I do that? Any help will be greatly appreciated, cause I'm stumped!
Mac OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved.  The first few times I installed apps on the emulator, I clicked the PhoneGap Build icon to run them.  But later appps installed under different names -- I guess based on info I entered into the config.xml file.

Still would be nice to know how to delete those apps from the emulator.  But at least the really mysterious part is explained -- why it ran a different app from the one I just built.  I was just clicking on the wrong icon.